# Castle Siege: Flaming arrows

Tags: design

I'm trying to think of ways to defend my LEGO castle. Is there a way I can shoot some flaming arrows into the hearts of the invaders? Maybe some burning oil?

Comment: Deciding how to defend your castle admittedly sounds like a subjective question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Burning oil is the easier of the two, since the [basic flame elements](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6126&name=Wave%20Rounded%20with%20Base%20Pins%20(Castle%20Dragon%20Flame,%20Seaweed,%20Water)&category=%5BEnergy%20Effect%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

can connect into a realistically looking stream of liquid fire:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Depicting individual arrows is a lot harder due to the absence of a single arrow piece (aside from the proportionally way oversized [harpoon piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18041&name=Minifigure,%20Weapon%20Harpoon,%20Smooth%20Shaft&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Weapon%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)), and adding a flame piece is even harder. Your best bet would probably be adding a [flame piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=37775&name=Candle%20Flame&category=%5BEnergy%20Effect%5D#T=S&C=98&O=%7B%22color%22:98,%22iconly%22:0%7D), [any of the](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=88964&name=Large%20Figure%20Barb,%20Flame%20(Ben%2010)&category=%5BLarge%20Figure%20Part%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) several [sizes available](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64647&name=Minifigure,%20Plume%20Feather%20Triple%20Compact%20/%20Flame%20/%20Water&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Headgear%20Accessory%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) to a shield:

[image]

Or use a [flame piece with a shaft](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=16768pb001&name=Bar%20%20%204L%20with%20Flame%20Protusions%20and%20Marbled%20Trans-Yellow%20Pattern&category=%5BBar%5D#T=S&C=17&O=%7B%22color%22:17,%22iconly%22:0%7D) as a combined arrow and flame:

[image]

But if 3rd party pieces are not out of question, you can get some convincing results, in this case with Brickarms arrows:

[image]

Comment: It may be worth noting that the current version of that flame element can no longer connect in this way.

Comment: I just emailed brickarms and they say they don't sell arrows anymore - too bad.

Comment: That flame shaft looks like it could work.  Could I combine one of those with a signal paddle (part #3900) somehow, perhaps with an appolo stud (part #85861). Then attach the paddle to a stoplight to allow for some arbitrary rotation.  Would that work?

Comment: @user3794648 Yes, both would work.